# Add delay to JS function

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, settimeout

I have this function:

```
$(document.body).ready(function() {
  var o = $(".hidden");
  $(".about_us").click(function() {
    o.hasClass("visible") ? o.removeClass("visible") : o.addClass("visible");
  });
});
```

and I want to add a delay to it. I'm trying the

```
setTimeout(...);
```

like this

```
$(document.body).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var o = $(".hidden");
    $(".about_us").click(function() {
      o.hasClass("visible") ? o.removeClass("visible") : o.addClass("visible");
    });
  }, 1000);
});
```

but it's not working.
Any help?

Comment: WHERE do you want the delay? It looks like you want to wait 1 second before adding the click listener but that doesn't make sense. Perhaps you want the delay to happen *after* the click? Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to add timeout 1 second before adding the click listener, but as @Moob said, it doesn't make sense.

If you want the delay to happen after the click, this code will work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".about_us").click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var o = $(".hidden");
      o.hasClass("visible") ? o.removeClass("visible") : o.addClass("visible");
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
window.setTimeout(
  function() {
    $(".about_us").click(function() {
      o.hasClass("visible") ? o.removeClass("visible") : o.addClass("visible");
    });
  }
  , 1000
);
```

The above is the correct syntax but not yet tested... This will work 100%.